# Why does a Cisco AP keep its static IP when erasing NVRAM?

Tags: cisco, wireless

When I erase the nvram on a Cisco AP (1252 and 1262), the static IP assigned to interface BVI1 is not erased. When I do a `show startup-config` it says there is no startup config. But it always boots with that IP until I manually set it to DHCP assigned. Then when I reboot (without saving) it comes up as DHCP.

If I erase it using the reset button on power up, the IP does not stick.

I can only imagine this is intended to keep from losing access to the AP when you erase the config. If this is the case, is there a command to wipe the IP too?

Extra details:

- IOS: 15
- Autonomous

Comment: Just to be clear... autonomous mode, or LWAP?  Also, what IOS version on the APs?

Comment: Updated with those answers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are correct, they leave the IP information so that you don't accidentally lose connectivity when working on an AP remotely.  As you noted, the button (which requires you to be local) will default the configuration including the IP.

You can also do this by entering the following command:

```
write default-config
```